# C# exception '0xC0020001: The string binding is invalid.'

Tags: c#, .net

I got this exception while I uninstall our program. The environment as below:

1. The program has a timer to do refresh operation per hour. The function call shown in dump files belong to the refresh operation,

> 00e4f058 547c62db (MethodDesc 53ec7398 +0x17 System.Windows.Forms.Timer+TimerNativeWindow.OnThreadException(System.Exception)), calling 53f8e4bc
>   00e4f064 53fcea31 (MethodDesc 53e50e94 +0xc1 System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr))
>   00e4f0e8 011fa397 (MethodDesc 011aac98 +0x8f XXX.XForm.TimerPoll()), calling (MethodDesc 6b8b34c8 +0 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo))

2. The refresh operation works well in most of the times. but if I do uninstall at the same time, there maybe a exception.

There are some articles which related with exception `0xC0020001`, but it is difficult to apply to my program. 
Someone says it is caused by unmanaged code call managed code while CLR has stop( it is mostly happen in my case, in a uninstall process ), I want to know what will cause CLR stop.

Comment: Sorry, the stack as below:

00e4f058 547c62db (MethodDesc 53ec7398 +0x17 System.Windows.Forms.Timer+TimerNativeWindow.OnThreadException(System.Exception)), calling 53f8e4bc
 
00e4f064 53fcea31 (MethodDesc 53e50e94 +0xc1 System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr))

00e4f0e8 011fa397 (MethodDesc 011aac98 +0x8f XXX.XForm.TimerPoll()), calling (MethodDesc 6b8b34c8 +0 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo))

Comment: Do not uninstall running program. Stop it first. You can e.g. use named `Mutex`es for this.

Comment: Thank you, Sinatr. We do stop the process at first. Let me check if we miss this process. It is a software with many process.

Answer (score -1):

This will show up when certain DLL don't link with native repos.

Recommended Solution is "Remove the entry point of the Managed DLL".

1. NOENTRY linking - In Solution Explorer, right-click the project node, click Properties. In the Property Pages dialog box, click Linker, click Command Line, and then add this switch to the Additional Options field.
2. msvcrt.lib - In the Property Pages dialog box, click Linker, click Input., and then add msvcrt.lib to the Additional Dependencies property.
3. nochkclr.obj - remove. On the Input page (same page as in the previous step), remove nochkclr.obj from the Additional Dependencies property.
4. Link in the CRT. On the Input page (same page as in the previous step), add __DllMainCRTStartup@12 to the Force Symbol References property.